# Can anyone explain why this does not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if all elements in a  collection contain a given property and that property contains a truthy value. i wrote the following algo which works correctly in most cases but not the following example and I cannot figure out why. Can anyone help?

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  // Is everyone being true
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    //console.log(collection[i].user);
    if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(pre)) {
      if (collection[i][pre] == true) continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var result = truthCheck([{
  "user": "Tinky-Winky",
  "sex": "male"
}, {
  "user": "Dipsy",
  "sex": "male"
}, {
  "user": "Laa-Laa",
  "sex": "female"
}, {
  "user": "Po",
  "sex": "female"
}], "sex");

console.log(result);
```

This returns false and only logs the first user even though the first user has the property and a value that should equate to true! It's killing me!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison between string to `true` is the problem. Instead use the value as the condition of the `if`, and let it cast it to boolean.

You can also skip the `hasOwnProperty` check, since you'll get a falsy value (`undefined`) when trying to get the value of a non existing property. In addition, return `false` when the value is falsy, instead of using `continue` to block the `return false`.

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    if (!collection[i][pre]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var result = truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}], "sex");

console.log(result);
```

A better option would be to use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  return collection.every(function(o) {
    return o[pre]; // will be falsy if it doesn't exist or the value is falsy
  });
}

var result = truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}], "sex");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Oh man can't beileve I did that!!! Need a coffee. :D Thanks for the every() suggestion, much more elegant,